# Java Android : onItemLongClick for listView doesn't respond

Tags: java, android, listview, listener

I'm developing an Android application.

I want to display a list of contacts (using **listview**) and I want to add 2 alerts dialogs: one by `onItemClickListener` and the other by `onItemLongClickListener`.

But the **`onItemLongClickListener` is never called**, just the `onItemClickListener`.
I already did it for another application, but here it doesn't work and I don't find why :/

My code:

```
public class ContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    private ContactAdapter adapter; //my adapter
    private ArrayList<Contact> contacts; //my list of contacts

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

        //here i init my "listView" and "contacts"

        adapter = new ContactAdapter(this, contacts);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e("longClick", "ok");
                return true;
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, final int position, long id) {
              //here i display a Dialog
           }
        });



    //some code
```

So, when I "simple click" on an item of the list, the dialog appears (ok).
But when I "long click" on an item of the list, the dialog appears and i don't see the Log...

(The item that i use for my ListView got just 2 EditText)

**PS: the XML where my listView is shown**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/white">

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:weightSum="100"
       android:id="@+id/screen">

       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/imageView4"
               android:background="@drawable/w_aff2" />
       </FrameLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:weightSum="100">

           <LinearLayout
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="20"
               android:weightSum="100">

               <ListView
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:id="@+id/listView" />
           </LinearLayout>

           <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="80">

           <LinearLayout
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:weightSum="3">

               <FrameLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_margin="14dp">

                   <ImageButton
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:id="@+id/button_back"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:background="@drawable/grey_button"
                       android:src="@drawable/i_back_blue" />
               </FrameLayout>

               <FrameLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_margin="14dp">

               </FrameLayout>

               <FrameLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_margin="14dp">

                   <ImageButton
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:id="@+id/button_add"
                       android:src="@drawable/i_add_blue"
                       android:background="@drawable/grey_button"
                       android:layout_gravity="center" />
               </FrameLayout>
           </LinearLayout>
       </FrameLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**PS2:** Don't look at the Log, I put that for example, but if i put anything else nothing happens, just the dialog appears...

**PS3:** The XML i use for each item of the listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/item_screen"
   android:background="@color/white">

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:weightSum="3"
       android:id="@+id/item_layout"
       android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
       android:padding="7dp">

       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:id="@+id/layout_label">

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="New Text"
               android:id="@+id/item_label"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:textSize="16dp" />
       </FrameLayout>

       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:id="@+id/empty_layout">

       </FrameLayout>

       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:id="@+id/layout_value"
           android:paddingTop="8dp"
           android:paddingBottom="8dp">

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="New Text"
               android:id="@+id/item_value"
               android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
               android:textSize="16dp" />
       </FrameLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**SOLUTION**
I had a onSwipeRight() on my listener, it blocked the onItemLongClickListener

here is the code that was blocking the listener

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getApplicationContext()) {
     public void onSwipeRight(){
         //some code
     }
});
```

Big thanks to ddb for his time :)

Comment: How are you seeing the log, you are doing error level log.

Comment: Could you share the xml where the list will be shown?

Comment: you have to probably change logcat filter from debug to error.

Comment: i edited the post with the xml, and the Log itself is not important, the thing is that nothing in the onItemLongClickListener works :/

Answer (score 1):

why are you passing a `new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener`?

just do like this below instead

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.e("longClick", "ok");
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Android Studio add the "AdapterView" by itself, if i remove it i have to add **import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener** and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: it still doesn't work :(
only the onItemClickListener is triggered

Comment: mmmm... then try to add property `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the listView in your xml, this way we should prevent EditText to take focus for the longClick

Comment: still the same result

Comment: please, share the xml that you use for each object of the list view

Comment: @Option, there is no reason why longClick listener should not work. Maybe somewhere in your app you configured something weird. So I suggest you to REMOVE everything, just leave only the list view and a simple label in each row, then try again if the long click works. Also I suggest a Toast instead of a log cat log. Then, continue by adding all the things you removed, just one at time and try if what you add breaks the code. So you can find your issue

Answer (score 0):

Do not set `listView.setLongClickable(true);`, `listView.setClickable(true);` in your java.

Neither

```
android:longClickable="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

Inside your xml

Comment: I added this because i saw a post that said to do that :/